# Statsmodels: Check R^2 with "fixed" parameters

Tags: python, statsmodels

I have run a regression on a `pandas` data frame, and obtained a set of parameters.

```
param = sm.ols(formula='sPrime ~ s', data=df).fit().params()
```

Now say I have a second data frame, `df2`, which has the same structure. I would like to compute the `R^2` of the just-obtained parameter values `param` with `df2`. I could dive into matrix calculations, but is there any way to do that using `statsmodels`?

Comment: It's not yet in statsmodels, see for example https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/2433/files